# Vue Js using forEach loop to compare array objects, prints out value multiple times

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I am comparing my array objects with my input value. It's suppose to print only one time saying **already inserted**  or **new id** but it compares each value and print it out multiple times.

Its because I am using `forEach` loop function to compare array objects. Is there a way to compare all the objects at the same time and print **already inserted**  or **new id** using console.log only one time?

*Link below consists of my code on* **JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/ud073bjy/20/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.find`:

```
var isFound = this.todos.find(function (entry, index) {
    if (entry.text === this.checkTravelerId) {
        return true;
    }
})

if (isFound) { 
    console.log("already inserted");
} else {
    console.log("new id");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping, I would use Javascript's **Array.find()** method [[documentation here]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    checkTravelerId: '',
    todos: [
      { text: "123", id:'1'},
      { text: "456", id:'2'},
      { text: "789", id:'3'},
      { text: "012", id:'4'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    dontknow(){
      var found = this.todos.find((todo) => {
        return todo.text == this.checkTravelerId
      })

      // If nothing is found, Array.find() returns undefined, which is false-y

      if (found) {
        console.log("already inserted")
      } else {
        console.log("new id")
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    checkTravelerId: '',
    todos: [
      { text: "123", id:'1'},
      { text: "456", id:'2'},
      { text: "789", id:'3'},
      { text: "012", id:'4'}
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    dontknow() {
      var result = this.todos.findIndex(player => this.checkTravelerId === player.text);
      if(result > -1) {
        console.log("already inserted");
      } else{
        console.log("new id");
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Player Input Field</h2>
   <input type="text" name="" v-model="checkTravelerId"/>
   <!-- if 123 inserted its suppose to say already inserted for only one time-->
   <!-- if inserted 908 its suppose to say new id for only one time -->
   <button variant="primary" v-on:click="dontknow();">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to using map, and array.indexOf

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    checkTravelerId: '',
    todos: [
      { text: "123", id:'1'},
      { text: "456", id:'2'},
      { text: "789", id:'3'},
      { text: "012", id:'4'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    dontknow(){

         if (this.todos.map(function(e) {return e.text}).indexOf(this.checkTravelerId) > -1) {
 console.log("already inserted");
}else {
         console.log('new id')

}

      },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Lanny Bose's great answer, I would suggest using **Array.some()** [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead to work directly with Boolean values, just replace "find" with "some".